# How to effectively use different font-weights depending on media queries

Tags: css, html, media-queries, google-fonts

google font-weight does not change when the screen size change. Is this a correct way to change the font-weight in the small screen using @import or there is another way?

```css
h1{
 font-family: 'Montserrat',sans-serif;
 font-size: 50px;
    }
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px)
{
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:600');
  h1{
  font-size:20px;
  font-weight:900;
   } }
```

```html
<!-- Google Font in Html-->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:100" rel="stylesheet">
    <h1> This is a text </h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the css @imports rule wich apparently doesn't work inside css @media rule you can use the html link tag with a media attribute.

Example Code:

HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400" media="only screen and (min-width: 481px)">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:700" media="only screen and (max-width: 480px)">
```

CSS:

```
body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif
}



@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) {
  h1 {
  font-weigth: 400;
}
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  h1 {
    font-weigth: 700;
  }
}
```

DEMO: https://codepen.io/quic5/pen/ebrmVg

Answer (score 0):

Write the google font
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:600'); at the  top of the css file it’s not needed in that section and then try.
if the same issue occurs then make the property important. Like
Font-weight:900 !important

Comment: Here we just only import Montserrat not all’s  therefore we write font-family=Montserrat

Comment: but you are of course not able to use a font-weight for a specific media query if you have not imported it

Comment: We just make changes in the property to semi-bold 600 while the default property is regular 400